# Is it bad practice to use element directives to organize html?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Is it bad practice to use directives just to organize html?

A simple example:

```
<header></header>
<sidebar></sidebar>
<main-content></main-content>
<footer></footer>
```

Each directive would just have the templateUrl attribute defined, nothing more. A project I'm currently working on would have perhaps 10-15 of these directives. I'm not sure if this is abusing directives or if it would have a negative impact on the loading time of the page.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, it would cause 4 requests to load the content of the page instead of just 1. It would be more efficient to use server-side templates to do that.

Comment: ... and, if you insist, there is already a directive to do this - [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

Comment: if you use anything more than once you could use directive...

Comment: It's not a bad practice if you're going to re-use the HTML in more than one place. It also cleans up the view where all of these elements are composited together. Note that `ng-include` creates an additional scope, which you can avoid by creating your own directive. And finally, there are solutions that concatenate HTML templates to avoid all the extra requests for template files.

Answer (score 2):

Development wise, it makes sense. Production wise, make sure you combine them to one file using a task manager in order to minimize the number of requests. Also, it will help you couple directives + controllers in a consistent way.